# Flask-GoogleMaps : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '.'

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I am trying a code from https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps

in app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_googlemaps import GoogleMaps
from flask_googlemaps import Map

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
GoogleMaps(app, key='mmm')

@app.route("/")
def mapview():
    mymap = Map()
    sndmap = Map()

    return render_template('example.html', mymap=mymap, sndmap=sndmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

in templates: `{{googlemap("my_awesome_map", lat=0.23234234, lng=-0.234234234, markers=[(0.12, -0.45345), ...])}}`

with

```
myproject/
    app.py
    templates/
        examples.html
```

And I got this error : *jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '.'*

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use markers, the template should like this:

on the head:

```
{{"decoupled-map"|googlemap_js(37.4419, -122.1419, markers=[(37.4419, -122.1419)])}}
```

on the body:

```
{{"decoupled-map"|googlemap_html(37.4419, -122.1419)}}
```

More examples: [Flask Google Maps Example](http://flaskgooglemaps.pythonanywhere.com/).